# Awkward PHP type error in function arguments

Tags: php, types

I have defined a function like this:

```
   private function mediaExist(string $entry) { ...
```

and I'm getting this type of error:

```
   ... must be an instance of string, string given, called in ...
```

Any help ?

Comment: You cannot do this with PHP. Here PHP is waiting for an object. `$entry` must be an object of type string.

Comment: Another point, if you are curious, Hack have a better check for [Type-Hinting](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). I do not recommand to use it for the moment in a production server. Hack is still in developpement.

Comment: @Debflav: I take it you meant to link to [hack's type-annotations](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.annotations.php) documentation, because the type-hinting link is just PHP's documentation. To the OP: yes, hack does support (a lot) stricter typing

Comment: Yes, this one is better. That the one I wanted to give. I've taken the first link without reading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP type-hints only work for classes or arrays:

```
function foo(array $bar, stdClass $object)
{//fine
}
```

But you can't type-hint primitives/scalar or resource types:

```
function bar(int $num, string $str)
{}
```

This would invoke the autoloader, which in term will attempt to find class definitions for the `int` and `string` classes, which obviously don't exist.
The rationale behind this is quite simple. PHP is a loosely typed language, and a numeric string can be turned into an int, or float, through type-juggling:

```
$foo = '123';
$bar = $foo*2;//foo's value is used as an int -> 123*2
```

type-hints were introduced to improve the OO capabilities of the language: a class/interface should be able to enforce a contract, through use of (among other things) type hinting.

If you want to ensure a given value is a string, you can use casts, or type-checking functions:

```
function foo($string)
{
    $sureString = (string) $string;//cast to string
    if ($sureString != $string)
    {//loose comparison, if they are not equal, the argument could not be converted to a string reliable
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(__FUNCTION__.' expects a string argument, '.get_type($string).' given');
    }
}
```

As far as *resources* are concerned (things like a file handler), it's just as easy to fix:

```
function foobar(/* resource hint is not allowed */ $resource)
{
    if (!is_resource($resource))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            sprintf(
                '%s expects a resource, %s given',
                __FUNCTION__,
                get_type($resource)
            );
        );
    }
}
```

In the end, the best thing to do when developing a sizable PHP project is to use doc-blocks, and a decent IDE. When you call a function/method, the IDE will use the doc-blocks to tell you what types are expected. It's the programmers job to ensure those criteria are met:

```
/**
 * Some documentation: what this function does, and how the arguments
 * are being used
 * @param array $data
 * @param string $key
 * @param string $errorMsg = ''
 * @return mixed
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 **/
function doStuff(array $data, $key, $errorMsg = '')
{
}
```

Comment: I'm not agree with the test in the sample of code `if ($sureString != $string)` your condition is not correct (too long to explain in comment). Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @Debflav: The advantage of `$sureString != $string` is that this check will allow objects with a `__toString` method to be used. Either way: `get_type() == 'string'`, `is_string` and all those options are equally valid. It all depends on the specific situation. I could've given a more comprehensive answer, but really, it all boiled down to what I said in the first two sentences: no primitive type-hints are allowed, use checks in the functions/methods themselves and handle errors accordingly

Comment: I'm fine with the whole answer (which I've upvoted). It's just because if you have `$string = 15;` you won't go in the condition. If you want a value of type string I don't guess that `15` is valid.

Comment: @Debflav: Fair point... it could well be that `15` is not a valid argument, but `'15'` wouldn't be valid then, either. But still `'15'`, as part of a query result set, should be used as an int, but is technically a string sometimes. Which brings us back to the same problem: how to check, and what to check is entirely dependent on the circumstances

Answer (score 1):

If you [omit the `string` type constraint, it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s). PHP is having trouble trying to infer the type of the string literal that you passed it, so it assumes that whatever it is, it's probably not the thing you're looking for -- which happens to be a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation of [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

That's why you got the error

Answer (score 0):

You can check in this way

```
function foo($string) {
    if (!is_string($string)) {
        trigger_error('No, you fool!');
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```