# Cakephp 3: how to implement events in helper

Tags: cakephp, events, cakephp-3.0, helper

in Cakephp 3 im trying to implement events in the helper class, this is example of what im trying to do:

```
protected $_View;

    public function __construct(View $View, $config = [])
    {
        //debug($View);die;
        $this->_View = $View;

        parent::__construct($View, $config);
        $this->_setupEvents();
    }

    /**
 * setup events
 */
    protected function _setupEvents() {
        $events = [
            'filter' => [$this, 'filter'],
        ];

        foreach ($events as $callable) {
                $this->_View->eventManager()->on("Helper.Layout.beforeFilter", $callable);
        }
    }

    public function filter(&$content, $options = array()) {
            preg_match_all('/\[(menu|m):([A-Za-z0-9_\-]*)(.*?)\]/i', $content, $tagMatches);
            for ($i = 0, $ii = count($tagMatches[1]); $i < $ii; $i++) {
                    $regex = '/(\S+)=[\'"]?((?:.(?![\'"]?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>\'"]))+.)[\'"]?/i';
                    preg_match_all($regex, $tagMatches[3][$i], $attributes);
                    $menuAlias = $tagMatches[2][$i];
                    $options = array();
                    for ($j = 0, $jj = count($attributes[0]); $j < $jj; $j++) {
                            $options[$attributes[1][$j]] = $attributes[2][$j];
                    }
                    $content = str_replace($tagMatches[0][$i], $this->menu($menuAlias, $options), $content);
            }
            return $content;
    }
```

But im getting warning for the line where im calling constructor of parent Helper class:

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to App\View\Helper\MenusHelper::__construct() must be an instance of App\View\Helper\View, instance of App\View\AppView given, called in C:\wamp\www\CookieCMS\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\HelperRegistry.php on line 142 and defined [APP/View\Helper\MenusHelper.php, line 26]
```

Is it possible to implement events in helper this way and what is it that im doing wrong?

Comment: The warning is basic type hinting in php. Just read, understand and do what it says? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Helper` class is already implements `EventlistenerInterface`, so as explained in the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners) all you have to do in your custom helper is return a proper array with required event name to callback mapping from `implementedEvents()` method.

So something like:

```
public function implementedEvents()
{
    $mapping = parent::implementedEvents();

    $mapping += [
        'Helper.Layout.beforeFilter' => 'someMethodOfYourHelper',
    ];

    return $mapping;
}
```