# how to pass float to function when declared parameters type in php

Tags: php

when i used wStrict typing, whatever I pass to the function, fatal error accurs :

```
function quote(float $a){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}
quote(1.1071212);
```

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to quote() must be an instance of float, double given

```
function quote(double $a){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
}
quote(1.1071212);
```

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to quote() must be an instance of double, double given, called

Comment: I believe you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably doing this in PHP 5? In which case scalar type hinting hadn't been introduced yet.

Instead it thinks `float` and `double` are classes that you're trying to type-hint.

The first one works in PHP 7 though. I've made example demonstrations of this for you here:

https://3v4l.org/A86Oo

https://3v4l.org/YLKEU