# Getting an error for double and boolean even boolean given

Tags: php, oop, php-7

As prior to one of the question available on SO i.e [How to resolve "Argument 1 passed to my_function() must be an instance of string, string given" prior to PHP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s). I've conducted test for this but I got strange error for `double` and `boolean` gives me an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to A::getData() must be an instance of double, float given,
>   Uncaught TypeError: Argument 6 passed to A::getData() must be an instance of boolean, boolean given,

```
class A{
    /**
     * [getData description]
     * @param  array   $data [description]
     * @param  string  $a    [description]
     * @param  int     $b    [description]
     * @param  boolean $c    [description]
     * @param  float   $d    [description]
     * @return [type]        [description]
     */
    public function getData(array $data, string $a, int $b,  float $f, double $d, boolean $c)
    {}
}

$a = new A();
$a->getData(["as"],"assasa",12345, 64.153454, 65.41, true);
```

You can check this over [here](https://3v4l.org/hUEnW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no double type hinting. And boolean should be changed to bool.
Your PHPDoc controls didn't match te parameters too

```
     /**
     * [getData description]
     * @param  array   $data [description]
     * @param  string  $a    [description]
     * @param  int     $b    [description]
     * @param  double   $f    [description]
     * @param  float $d     [description]
     * @param  bool $c    [description]
     * @return [type]        [description]
     */

     public function getData(array $data, string $a, int $b, $f, float $d, bool $c)
     {

     } 



$a->getData(["as"],"assasa",12345,65.41,64.153454 , true);
```

Comment: Yeah got it. After you answer I gone through the [php.net manual and found an example given over there](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php#117907). Thanks need to do some research work before post anyways once again thanks