# Value of associative array element not recognized as string

Tags: php, arrays, string

The var_dump of the associative array $myArray is as follows:

```
array (size=522)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 1
      'url' => string 'introduction' (length=12)
      'title' => string 'Introduction' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 2
      'url' => string 'first_steps' (length=11)
      'title' => string 'First steps' (length=11)
  2 => ...
```

When I assign the values of elements in the associative array to a function, to perform some string manipulation, I get an error:

> "Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to doStringManipulation() must be an instance of string, string given, ..."

The string manipulation is called inside a foreach loop:

```
foreach($myArray as $row){
    ...
    $s = doStringManipulation((string) $row['url']); // triggers error
    ...
}

function doStringManipulation(string str){
    ...
    return $result; // string
}
```

Whether or not I cast $row['url'] to string doesn't make a difference. I always get the error, even though var_dump confirms that the element value is a string.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: Have you tried not placing $row['url'] as a parameter but for example "test" ? (try without the cast)

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s

Comment: @Robert: using 5.5

Comment: @Lazar Petrovic: thanks, indeed, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're not using php 7.

The error states that it requires an instance of string (which php does not have), this is because you are type hinting `string` in `function doStringManipulation(string str){`. Type hinting does not work on anything but on arrays and objects.

My suggestion:

```
function doStringManipulation($str) { // assuming 'str' was a typo here
    if ( ! is_string($str)) {
         return '';
    }

    ...

    return $result; // string
}
```

For more info see: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: Thanks, this is the most complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use php version 5.0-5.6. you cant specify string as function argument.
Code must looks like

```
/**
* @var String str
*/ 
function doStringManipulation(str){
    ...
    return $result; // string
}
```

Or update php up to 7

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I was getting code hints that applied to php 7 for some reason.