# Argument 1 passed to function must be an instance of WP_REST_Request, string given

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have a plugin that I'm working on, and the endpoint is behaving oddly. I'm getting the error mesage seen in the title of this post; I have noted [past threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/how-to-resolve-must-be-an-instance-of-string-string-given-prior-to-php-7) that reference similar problems, but there aren't any helpful solutions there. My code:

```
function get_awesome_params( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  $parameters = $request->get_params();
  return new WP_REST_Response($parameters, 200);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('cbd/v1', '/cbdproducts', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'get_awesome_params',
    'args' => array(),
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return true;
    }
  ));
});
```

If I remove the typing and just pass in '$request', then it thinks it's just a string and the getter called in the function doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value of $request? can you va_dump it!?

Comment: I also have same problem

Comment: Does anyone know how to import  WP_REST_Request to my plugin class

Comment: Smit, looking at code that worked for me in production,  this line: ` $parameters = $request->get_params();` got changed to ` $parameters = json_decode( $request->get_body(), true);`

Answer (score 0):

**Put backslash in WP_REST_Request may be use are using namespace. SO code must be**

```
function get_awesome_params( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  $parameters = $request->get_params();
  return new WP_REST_Response($parameters, 200);
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
  register_rest_route('cbd/v1', '/cbdproducts', array(
    'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::CREATABLE,
    'callback' => 'get_awesome_params',
    'args' => array(),
    'permission_callback' => function () {
      return true;
    }
  ));
});
```