# Argument 1 passed to myFunction() must be an instance of string, string given, called in

Tags: php, string, function, arguments, instance

i have this function:

```
function myFunction(string $name) {
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db(...); 

    $insertplayer="INSERT INTO `...`(....)
    VALUES (......')";
    if (!mysql_query($insertplayer,$db))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo 'done for player N°'.$id;
    mysql_close($db);
}
```

and the form i use:

```
<form action="insertplayer.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nameplayer" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

But when i do this, i have this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to myFunction() must be an instance of string, string given, called in C:.... on line 23 and defined in C:...
```

I have this error with the int problem. How can i resolved it ?

Comment: you don't need to use dataType string in php in your function

Comment: Type hinting is not for primative types, php is looking for a string class that does not exist. Remove that type hint: myFunction($name) {

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call the function you defined ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Really PHP? "Argument 1 passed to my\_function() must be an instance of string, string given"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s)

Comment: Thanks, i will just need remove string in myfunction(string $....)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when passing string into method with type hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112791/error-when-passing-string-into-method-with-type-hinting)

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the primitive data type from the function declaration.  PHP does not require type hints for primitive data types.

```
function myFunction($name) {
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db(...); 

    $insertplayer="INSERT INTO `...`(....)
    VALUES (......')";
    if (!mysql_query($insertplayer,$db))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo 'done for player N°'.$id;
    mysql_close($db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a block of code to check type at the beginning of each function you are writing looking like this:

```
function myFunction($myScalar) {
    if (!is_string($myScalar)) {
        throw new Exception(...);
    }

    ...
}
```

You can register an errorhandler comparing the given type with your hint and if for example `string==string` you can ignore the error.

See User Notes on the manual page for some examples

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration