# How to get "lavary/crunz" to work with twig

Tags: php, twig, slim-3

Ok, ill try to explain as easy as possible:
In my PHP Web Application in which i have setup some automated Tasks with `"lavary/crunz"`.

The Problem i am facing is when trying to use "Twig Templating engine" to create my Email Body, somehow it wont work and i the error message i get when debugging is not helpfull.:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static function _testTask()
        {
        $receiver = ['email'=>COMPANY_EMAIL,'name'=>COMPANY_NAME];
        return function() use($receiver)
               {
                $mail = new \MailerCtrl();

                $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem("views/templates");
                $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader,["cache" => "views/cache"]);

                $content = array('name'=>'My Name','age'=>25);
                $subject = 'Something';
                $mail->send($subject,$receiver,$twig->render('report.html.twig', $content));
               };
    }
}



$schedule->run(MyClass::_testTask())->cron('* * * * *');
```

My `MailerCtrl` class is a simple PHPMailer representation which expects the html body i expect to render from `$twig->render('report.html.twig', $content);`

Is there another or even a better way to accomplish this? When i call this script from http it works as expected but when running it through "crunz" i am getting this error:

PHP Catchable fatal error:

> Argument 1 passed to Twig_Filter::__construct() must be an instance
>   of string, string given, called in
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/*/httpdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php
>   on line 139 and defined in
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/*/httpdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Filter.php on
>   line 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is running PHP 7
and

> "lavary/crunz"

via PHP command line isn't running PHP 7 as Twig 2.0 is required at least PHP 7 as describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888528/1865829

Update your PHP command line to 7 and it should work.